# How to take a screenshot with colors as they appear in night mode

Tags: colors, screenshot, tools

I often find myself in situations where some images have nicer looking colors in the night-mode. I often want to screenshot them. Unfortunately, what I get is the original image.

Is there any way to get the image as it appears on the display?

PS: A lot of times, I want to pick colors from images in night-mode. If it is not possible/easy to take screenshots in night-mode, can you please suggest a way to pick those colors?

Comment: I suppose the obvious (using a camera or your phone) doesn't work because the image quality is too low, right?

Comment: @terdon Yes it doesn't work because I won't be able to get accurate colors.

Comment: @Mogli I had looked at that question before asking this one. The problem was that there were no answers and the comment recommending shutter had zero upvotes.